# Unhandled Rejection (Error): This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
await contract.methods.set(98,"h").send({ from: accounts[0]});
```

I am trying to store uint and string but the error always came up:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.

Its work fine when I try to store the uint only. I also have changed my smart contract and tested on remix and it works fine to store both uint and string.

Answer (score 0):

solved. Sorry I forget to add the file in the migrate floder.

Comment: Can you add more details? How the migration file looks like.